# Why the variance-covariance matrix of `glmer` in R is not symmetric?

Tags: r, error-handling, rounding, glm, mixed-models

I don't understand how a variance-covariance matrix may not be symmetric.
Is it due to the way the numbers are rounded?

If we take the example presented on the `merDeriv` package to get the full variance-covariance matrix (fixed and random parameters):

```
lme4fit <- glmer(corr ~ jmeth + (1 | item), data = finance,
                  family = binomial, nAGQ = 20)
 # variance covariance matrix for all parameters
 nnn=vcov(lme4fit, full = TRUE, ranpar = "var")
 isSymmetric(nnn)
[1] FALSE
```

The problem is that I use the variance-covariance matrix obtained in `glmer` and `merDeriv` in `rtmvnorm` (function to generate numbers from a multivariate normal distribution) for Monte-Carlo simulations.
However, I have errors in the following, because the variance-covariance matrix never passes the test of

```
checkSymmetricPositiveDefinite(H, name = "H")
```

included in the `rtmvnorm` function for the sigma (Covariance matrix used for the random numbers generation).

What should I do?

Comment: Try `isSymmetric(unname(nnn))`. From the help page `?isSymmetric`, section Details: *"Note that a matrix m is only symmetric if its rownames and colnames are identical. Consider using unname(m)."*

Comment: In fact, this causes me error in my code. The `isSymmetric` is included in a package function. I solved this problem by forcing the symmetry of the matrix.